# Unable to send E-mails using Node-RED

Tags: gmail, node-red

This is my flow where I'm trying to send an Email based on data from a csv file.

[image]

This is the error that I am getting in the debug window. I tried sending e-mails using Node-RED, but I couldn't

[image]

I used the E-mail Node to send the mail from one account to another. The account from which I'm sending the Email from requires it's username and password, where the password which for some reason runs back to it's default one as below even when I type in the right password

[image]

One solution was to Enable the Less secure app access which is disabled by Google right now. So I tried using Yahoo mail instead and the issue still prevails.

Please let me know if there is any other way for me to send an E-mail. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not user your Yahoo email address/password to send emails via the Google SMTP Servers.

You will need to follow the first item on the list provided by the error message and create a Application Specific Password to allow you to authenticate the Email Node with the Goolge SMTP server.

Details of how to create an Application Specific Password are found here:

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en